# images not showing up after build angular project

Tags: javascript, image, angular, angular-cli, production-environment

i have already finished coding my app and i try to build it to production mode ,and after testing the app , i see that images not showing in the app as logo ...
but the the devloppement mode it's ok .
 this is the tree of my project :

[you can see here the structure of the project in production mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVpOT.png)

is it neccessary to add webpack to my project to solve this problem ?

i want also to ask you about the function of webpack , because my project is not including webpack and i found that is neccessary to have it my application .

Comment: are your images in `dist/assets`? are they referenced correctly in your HTML?
as for webpack, angular cli uses webpack, no need to add it.

Comment: How did you build your application? Did you use `deployUrl` or `base-href`? Are you getting 404 for images in console?

Comment: @AhmedMusallam  , in my assets , i have a folder named images that contain my images , but in html is not referenced correctly i have to delete some caracter like '../' from the url and then it resolved .

Comment: @ulubeyn i have deployed try this command : ng build --prod .

Comment: problem resolved , i just have change the href from "../assets/images/logo.png" to "assets/images/logo.png "

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Changing the image path from "../assets/images/logo.png" to "assets/images/logo.png" into prod build should not be the ideal solution. Looking for some descent solution. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Personally i don't even know what it is a webpack (and i'm not proud of it), but i know why you are having that issue.

You should take off the slash in the beginning of the images paths. So you have to use <img src="assets/image.png" and not <img src="/assets/image.png"

just to add on the @CybrRob 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Angular looks for the images in the assets folder, so in your html, use <img src="assets/image.png" Don't include the "../"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this explanation may solve the question, including a sample code of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. I suggest you to edit your answer to add some code example, Have a look here → [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just change your path from

```
<img src="../../assets/g5.jpg" alt="">
```

to

```
<img src="assets/g5.jpg"  alt="">
```